# Is there a 2003 compatibility setting in Visual Studio 2008 (compiler compatibility, not project / solution files)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

I have a Visual Studio 2003 solution that I've opened with VS2008, and it converted successfully. However, it won't build because the code contains some things that were acceptable under Visual Studio 2003, but simply don't fly under Visual Studio 2008. Changing the code would be really difficult in my particular situation. Is there a flag or something that I can set which would use 2003-compatible compilation?

Cheers,
Frank

Comment: Which particular things? There are a number of language support switches which (IIRC) changed their default settings between 2003 .NET and 2008.

Comment: The main thing right now is that there are some global const variables that are declared with no type specifier. I've never seen it before, but my guess is that it previously defaulted to int. Here is an example:

const myConst = 5;

Comment: I'm afraid you're out of luck. There isn't any way to get the relaxed "default int" behaviour in VS2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a compatibility switch.  You'll have to install VS2k3 if you can't update the source code.

Answer (score 0):

The default warning level in VS2008 is -W3.  Change the warning level to -W2 (more forgiving).  I had the same issue moving from VC6 to VS2008.

Right-click on the project; select Properties; Warning Level is set in the Compiler section.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I tried this, as well as setting it to W1, however I am still not able to get the code to compile. I may be out of luck! (without getting a copy of 2003 hehehe)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely  you missed somthing.othetwise vs2008 does not support any such type of decleration.